# How do we use spring security + Oauth2 client credentials for Service to Service ( fetch Auth token followed by resources)

Tags: java, spring, rest, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

sorry if this feels a little over worded question. I have a a endpoint which provides Auth Bearer token, using which i can fetch resources from another endpoint ( same domain though).  I already have the client credentials ID/secret.

I wanted to see some sample code of how this is configured using Service to Service without a UI for logging in pls.

I read that RestTemplate and OauthRestTempate is deprecated and we should be using Web client ( https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-webclient-servlet)

but I am bit a confused on how this is actually implemented.
I wanted to see the format for the application.yml file format, because i understand the format varies depending on what grant type we use. 
also is there a mongodb spring jar that i can Autowire, so that i can move the resources that i get to the db directly please.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good start for your case!

Take a look also at the different flow types in OpenId Connect.

Spring Boot + OAuth 2 Client Credentials Grant - Hello World Example

https://www.javainuse.com/spring/springboot-oauth2-client-grant

Comment: Hi Armando, i see this is also configured specifically for Web UI auth flow pls. I was looking for something specific to service-to-service connection, which using the client credentials/secret to get the Oauth token, store in inmemory, and use that token to get the resources and store in a db.

Comment: I have updated my answer. you need the  Client Credentials Grant. This should be the appropriate example...